# sliderInput values as dataframe in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

in course of an experiment I am trying to build in shiny I would like to **print a .csv** including values from different **sliderInputs**. Therefore I want to use them as **dataframe**. I included a shortened example of what I am trying to do below.

However, if I run the code as below it returns

> Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observer()?

If I do wrap the inputs into reactive() however it returns

> cannot coerce class ‘c("reactiveExpr", "reactive", "function")’ to a data.frame

Does anyone have a solution to this?

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
    br(),
    sliderInput(inputId = "S1", label= "S1", min = 1, max = 10, value = 5),
    br(),
    sliderInput(inputId = "S2", label= "S2", min = 1, max = 10, value = 5),
    br(),
    plotOutput("P1", width = "40vw"),
    actionButton("printData", "Print")
    
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    
    
    data <- reactive({ c(input$S1, input$S2) })
    
    data1 <- c(input$S1) 
    data2 <- c(input$S2)
    
    dataframe <-data.frame(Column1 = c(data1, data2))

    
    output$P1 <- renderPlot({
        barplot(data(), horiz=TRUE, names.arg=c("S2", "S1"), xlim = c(0,10))
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$printData, {
        write.csv2(dataframe, "test.csv", row.names = TRUE)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  sliderInput(inputId = "S1", label= "S1", min = 1, max = 10, value = 5),
  br(),
  sliderInput(inputId = "S2", label= "S2", min = 1, max = 10, value = 5),
  br(),
  plotOutput("P1", width = "40vw"),
  actionButton("printData", "Print")
  
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive({ 
    data.frame(Column1 = c(input$S1, input$S2))
  })
  
  output$P1 <- renderPlot({
    barplot(data()[["Column1"]], horiz=TRUE, names.arg=c("S1", "S2"), xlim = c(0,10))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$printData, {
    write.csv2(data(), 
               "test.csv", row.names = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you're just starting out with Shiny you can try reading this: https://mastering-shiny.org/, which is really helpful.

`input` values are reactive. You've assigned them using `reactive` to `data`, so it is not clear why you are then assigning them individually to `data1` and `data2`. You won't be able to do that because then you are trying to do something with reactives outside of a reactive context. This then means you can't create `dataframe`. In my example, I create a data frame using `reactive`, which I then call in my renderer and observer - note that to use reactives, you need to call them using `()`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this helpful reply.

When I try to rebuild this in the code of my application, it returns the erroe "subscript out of bounds" instead of the barplot in which I insert the [[]]. 

I found the error in ProgrammingR, but I don´t fully understand what exactly is causing it.

I did not include the code because it is quite lengthy, but if required I will share it of course.

Comment: So that could be because the `[[` is subsetting a column in `data` that does not exist. If you are picking out the column using a numeric column index, you need to make sure that a column exists at that index. You could also use the column name - in this example, instead of 'Column1' in `data()[["Column1"]]`, you should have the name of the column in `data`.

Comment: edit - nevermind, i found the problem. Thanks a lot!